# Read and write same memory from different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, thread-synchronization

I have a simple class which sends requests asynchronously.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ISender _sender;

    public MyClass(ISender sender)
    {
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public Task<string> SendAsync(string input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _sender.SendAsync(input, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public interface ISender
{
    Task<string> SendAsync(string input, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

All looks simple, until the following requirement: _sender can be changed at runtime.

New implementation of MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ISender _sender;

    public MyClass(ISender sender)
    {
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public Task<string> SendAsync(string input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _sender.SendAsync(input, cancellationToken);
    }

    public void SenderChanged(object unused, SenderEventArgs e)
    {
        ISender previous = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _sender, SenderFactory.Create(e.NewSenderConfig));
        previous.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Obviously this code is not thread-safe. I would need to introduce `lock` in both `SendAsync` and `SenderChanged` to make sure that _sender is always the up-to-date object. 
But I expect the `SenderChanged` to be called once per day let's say, and `SendAsync` (reading the _sender object) to be called 10000/second.
`Lock` and context switching would kill the performance of this code.

Is there a possible way to handle this with low level locking? Or how would you solve this problem knowing the above requirement?

Comment: Note that the cost of uncontested locks is *extremely* small.  Even at 10,000 calls a second, it's quite plausible that it won't be a problem given that the lock will (approximately) always be free when taken.

Comment: Hi Servy, the SendAsync will be called from multiple threads and each thread will have to wait to take the lock. That would cause context switching.

Comment: Can you not structure things such that each thread has its own sender, and they aren't all trying to share one?  I wouldn't expect it's send operation to be safe to be called from multiple threads in the first place.

Comment: unfortunately no, I have to use the same _sender. Sender.SendAsync implementations  are fine to be called from multiple threads

Comment: What is the expected use case of your previous sender when a new one comes in? Your code indicates it's going to be disposed, but if it's in the process of an async operation, what *should* happen to it? Should it complete, abort, etc?

Comment: @Tejs fair question. The Dispose() will first wait for all the In-Flight tasks to finish. Then it will  dispose. A way to solve the above issue is that once the object is "requested to dispose" I will throw an ObjectDisposedException from the _sender.SendAsync implementation. But that's pretty ugly, because the client will need to know this behavior and have some retry logic

Comment: Because it sounds like you could fix this with a design change. You need a queue of operations, and your sender is operating on that queue per unit of work. Then when a new sender comes in, you simply stop the old one from dequeueing work into a local queue (with a marker variable I think), then when your local queue empties from your old sender, it can be disposed without waiting. EDIT: A sort of producer / consumer pattern

Comment: @DanDinu - What is the 'raceability' of 1) the new sender event and 2) new requests? Do you expect the operations to be perfectly serialized? Is it alright if I process a few requests using the old sender while the new one is being installed?

Comment: @antiduh It's fine to process few requests with the old sender as long as it is not disposed. But it can happen that Dispose is called just before a request comes in through the "old" (previous) sender, so the request would go through a disposed sender, which is not ok. (I'm afraid here of caches of the old value of _sender, and memory synchronization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use a reader-writer lock, specifically [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is a monitor-like lock that optimizes for frequent read access and infrequent write access, and it supports multiple concurrent readers and a single writer, which appears to be exactly your use case.

However, it does seem to come at a moderate cost. I wrote two tests - one that uses a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to do things correctly, and one which uses your implementation with the only change being an disposed-exception retry loop. In my case I changed senders 20 times, once every 10 seconds. This is vastly shorter than your proposed use case, but does serve as an estimate of the performance difference.

In the end:

- The reader/writer lock was able to get through 2878 workunits per millisecond.
- The bare with retry was able to get through 9940 workunits per millisecond.

Where a 'workunit' is calling the DoWork method which calls `Thread.SpinWait(100)`. Code is posted below if you'd like to test for yourself.

**Edit:**

I adjusted the `Thread.SpinWait()` call to change the balance of how much time is spent on locking versus 'working'. With a spin-wait of around 900-1000 on my machine, both implementations ran at the same, about 1000 work-units / millisecond. That should've been obvious from the results above, but I did want to just run the sanity check.

As it is, the original results show that we're able to process about 2.8 million requests a second using the lock; at least on my machine which is a 4-core Intel CPU, "Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q9650 @ 3.00 GHz". Given that you're striving for 10k requests/second, it looks like you've got about an order of magnitude headroom before the locking starts to become a significant proportion of your CPU usage.

---

```
#define USE_READERWRITER

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestProject
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            SenderDispatch dispatch = new SenderDispatch();

            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();

            workers.Add( new Worker( dispatch, "A" ) );
            workers.Add( new Worker( dispatch, "B" ) );
            workers.Add( new Worker( dispatch, "C" ) );
            workers.Add( new Worker( dispatch, "D" ) );

            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main thread";
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

            watch.Start();
            workers.ForEach( x => x.Start() );

            for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 10000 );
                dispatch.NewSender();
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Stopping..." );

            workers.ForEach( x => x.Stop() );
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine( "Stopped" );

            long sum = workers.Sum( x => x.FinalCount );

            string message = 
                "Sum of worker iterations: " + sum.ToString( "n0" ) + "\r\n" +
                "Total time:               " + ( watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0 ).ToString( "0.000" ) + "\r\n" +
                "Iterations/ms:            " + sum / watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            MessageBox.Show( message );
        }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        private SenderDispatch dispatcher;
        private Thread thread;
        private bool working;

        private string workerName;

        public Worker( SenderDispatch dispatcher, string workerName )
        {
            this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
            this.workerName = workerName;

            this.working = false;
        }

        public long FinalCount { get; private set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            this.thread = new Thread( Run );
            this.thread.Name = "Worker " + this.workerName;

            this.working = true;
            this.thread.Start();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            long state = 0;

            while( this.working )
            {
                this.dispatcher.DoOperation( workerName, state );
                state++;
            }

            this.FinalCount = state;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            this.working = false;

            this.thread.Join();
        }
    }

    public class SenderDispatch
    {
        private Sender sender;

        private ReaderWriterLockSlim senderLock;

        public SenderDispatch()
        {
            this.sender = new Sender();
            this.senderLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim( LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion );
        }

        public void DoOperation( string workerName, long value )
        {

#if USE_READERWRITER
            this.senderLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                this.sender.DoOperation( workerName, value );
            }
            finally
            {
                this.senderLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
#else 
            bool done = false;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    this.sender.DoOperation( workerName, value );
                    done = true;
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
            }
            while( !done );
#endif

        }

        public void NewSender()
        {
            Sender prevSender;
            Sender newSender;

            newSender = new Sender();

#if USE_READERWRITER
            this.senderLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                prevSender = Interlocked.Exchange( ref this.sender, newSender );
            }
            finally
            {
                this.senderLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
#else
            prevSender = Interlocked.Exchange( ref this.sender, newSender );
            prevSender.Dispose();

#endif
            prevSender.Dispose();

        }
    }

    public class Sender : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposed;

        public Sender()
        {
            this.disposed = false;
        }

        public void DoOperation( string workerName, long value )
        {
            if( this.disposed )
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException( 
                    "Sender",
                    string.Format( "Worker {0} tried to queue work item {1}", workerName, value ) 
                );
            }

            Thread.SpinWait( 100 );
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```